# How can I add a lazy="loading" attribute to img in #TEXTE in SPIP

Tags: image, lazy-loading, spip

In Spip 4.2, I am trying to automatically add the `loading="lazy"` attribute to all my `<img />` in `#TEXTE` to implement lazy loading in my articles.

I tried to find and replace "img src" by "img loading="lazy" src" but it does not work:

```
[(#TEXTE|replace{<img}{<img loading="lazy"})]
```

and `#TEXTE|extraire_attribut{'loading', 'lazy'}` does not seem to affect anything.

How can I add a lazy="loading" attribute to img in #TEXTE in SPIP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding quotation marks and removing the `<` character worked. To avoid changes the words in the text starting by `img` the beginning of the first default attribute can be quoted as `img src` given the code to insert an image is `<img src=... />`

```
(#TEXTE|replace{"img src","img loading='lazy' src"})
```

This might not be the most computationally efficient way of doing it since it has a search and replace function but pages can be cached using various plugins to avoid repeating this too often.